# How to group Multi value parameters

Tags: reporting-services

I'm looking to group the options of a multivalue parameter. What i need is an option to display parameters like this and when 'Team 1' is checked, all three options(Davis, Arun, Scott) needs to be checked and being able to check 'Cary' alone without 'Mary' or 'Team 2' being checked. Is this kind of grouping possible using SSRS?

- Select All
- Team 1

  - Davis
  - Arun
  - Scott
- Team 2

  - Mary
  - Cary

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is have cascading parameter.. with default values in it based on the parent parameter.

Say Team1 and Team2 are values for Parameterteam (parent parameter).. have this as a multiselect parameter so you get select all.

Then based on your selection on parameterteam, have another parameter called parameterteammembers. This parameterteammembers will gets it's value based on Parameterteam.. makes sense?

I do not think what you want to achieve is possible in SSRS